# Filter map and return array of ids

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have this structure :

```
var entities = {
  1: {'name': 'Fred', 'age': 35},
  2: {'name': 'Hans', 'age': 47},
  3: {'name': 'Bert', 'age': 27}
}
```

I need something like :

```
var ids = entities.filter( p => p.age > 30);
```

which should return an array :

```
[1, 2]
```

Is there a convenient way to do this ? e.g. Lodash, etc ?

Comment: What isn't working for you?

Comment: @JeremyThille there sort of is. It's called "users". And I'm not trying to be a smartass towards *you* - this is more to call out the users as being random. I've seen no effort questions or answers get upvotes within minutes of being posted or decent ones getting downvoted within the same time either. I suspect some users of just mass downvoting anything they find with little reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use the `Object.keys` combined with `Array.prototype.filter`

```js
var entities = {
  1: {'name': 'Fred', 'age': 35},
  2: {'name': 'Hans', 'age': 47},
  3: {'name': 'Bert', 'age': 27}
}
const result = Object.keys(entities).filter(key =>  entities[key].age > 30);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

`filter` only works on `Array`, but there is something interesting: Your object looks like an array!

People that use javascript use to say:

> if it walks like a duck and it quacks like a duck, then it is a duck

About this context, something that acts like an array is just an object with numbers as keys *plus* a `length` property. And watching your object, you just miss the length property!

Let's add the `length` property in this way:

```
entities.length = Math.max(...Object.keys(entities)) + 1; // 4
```

Then you can transform your array-like object in a real array:

```
const array = Array.from(entities);
```

And in the end, you can use all your `Array` methods on it, also filter:

```
array
  .filter(p => p.age > 30)
  .map((obj, index) => index);
```

Comment: I never thought of objects like that. Still, in my case I'm not sure if this would work when the Id's aren't sequential, say they come from database --> entities = {97: {...}, 114: {...}, 43: {...}}.

Comment: @Wolf359 yes, that's right. You shouldn't use it if the index/id has some importance. Because it will transform the object in an array, and in an array the index is only used to locate the element and it won't be stable

Comment: Also in my example, the index aren't the initial ones, since I'm using `map` after `filter`!

Answer (score 2):

You can use lodash `reduce` method. It works for both arrays and objects. 
Example:

```
var entities = {
  1: {'name': 'Fred', 'age': 35},
  2: {'name': 'Hans', 'age': 47},
  3: {'name': 'Bert', 'age': 27}
}

var result = _.reduce(entities, (acc, o, key) => {
    if(o.age >= 35) { // add your condition here
       acc.push(key);
     }
    return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result); // ["1", "2"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could get the entries, filter the age and return the keys (which are obviously strings).

```js
var entities = { 1: {'name': 'Fred', 'age': 35 }, 2: {'name': 'Hans', 'age': 47 }, 3: {'name': 'Bert', 'age': 27 } },
    result = Object
        .entries(entities)
        .filter(({ 1: { age } }) => age > 30)
        .map(([k]) => k);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through keys of `entities` and check for age condition for particular key in `entities` and filter.

```js
var entities = {
  1: {'name': 'Fred', 'age': 35},
  2: {'name': 'Hans', 'age': 47},
  3: {'name': 'Bert', 'age': 27}
}

let op = Object.keys(entities).filter(e=> entities[e].age > 30)

console.log(op)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use _.map()    and _.keys() to achieve like the code below

```
var i= -1;
var keys=_.keys(entities);
var person= _.map(entities, function(p) {
    i++;
    if (p.age>30) return keys[i];
});
```

Comment: I need an array of id's, not array of objects